# List AWS instances by Tag Name using python

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I have small python code for listing all EC2 instances across region, but I cannot find how to get Tag 'Name' while I am printing results.
With instance.tags it prints all tags, but I want only 'Name'

Code example:

```
import boto3

access_key = "xyw"
secret_key = "xywz"

client = boto3.client('ec2', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,region_name='us-east-1')

ec2_regions = [region['RegionName'] for region in client.describe_regions()['Regions']]

for region in ec2_regions:
  conn = boto3.resource('ec2', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
               region_name=region)
  instances = conn.instances.filter()
  for instance in instances:
    if instance.state["Name"] == "running":
      print (region, instance.key_name, instance.public_dns_name, instance.image_id, instance.instance_type, instance.tags)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the [`tags`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.tags) so you need to add this in your code

```
  for tag in tags:
    if tag["Key"] == 'Name':
        instancename = tag["Value"]
```

something like this

```
import boto3

access_key = "xyw"
secret_key = "xywz"

client = boto3.client('ec2', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,region_name='us-east-1')

ec2_regions = [region['RegionName'] for region in client.describe_regions()['Regions']]

for region in ec2_regions:
  conn = boto3.resource('ec2', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
               region_name=region)
  instances = conn.instances.filter()
  for instance in instances:
    if instance.state["Name"] == "running":
      instancename = ''
      for tag in instance.tags:
        if tag["Key"] == 'Name':
            instancename = tag["Value"]
      print (region, instance.key_name, instance.public_dns_name, instance.image_id, instance.instance_type, instancename)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work, or I do not know how to pull only Tag name, instead all tags.

Comment: you cannot really pull only Tag Name, you need to loop through the tags to find the correct tag name and get its value

Comment: Agree @Frédéric Henri it's not trivial and easy to setup Thanks for pointing out. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

we can use boto's

> get_all_instances

which can take tags as filter

Refer: http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/ec2.html

```
 def list_nodes():
     filter_tags = {
        "tag:Environment": "xyz",
        "tag:Project": "abc",
        "tag:Test": "test",
        "instance-state-name": 'running'
    }
    boto_ec2 = EC2Connection(..)
    reservations = boto_ec2.get_all_instances(filters=filter_tags)
    instances = [i for r in reservations for i in r.instances]
    return instances
```

Comment: @FrédéricHenri You have boto3 implementation. Doesnt harm to have one in boto2 as well. Question doesnt state boto version anyhow